# Android: Internet connection cannot be established on my app with some devices

Tags: android, httpclient, gprs

ich have written an app for android which has to download data from a website. All in all it works pretty well but i heard from some users that they the internet connection doesn't work when they use internet access via mobile internet. With the WLAN there are no problems and on my mobile phone it even works with mobile internet. I already ensured myself that the users who has got these problems do have internet access on other apps with their mobile internet...
Here is the source code, where I establish the connection.

```
String urlString = "http://google.com";
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setDoInput(true);
// Starts the query
conn.connect();
InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "ISO-8859-"));
String line = "";
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    line //do sthg with line
}
```

I hope that i gave enough information to you guys the help me to solve that problem

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could delete those

```
conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
```

Comment: The Problem is not that Timeout-time has been excessed. If the user tries to access to the internet the connection closes immediatly...

Comment: ofcource I added that to the manifest, otherwise the other people would not be able to connect to the internet

Comment: Do you have diagnostic tools to see which application or service is closing the connection?

Comment: If you can reproduce the issue you could use the AT&T ARO tool to analyze what is closing the connection and monitor network activity. This can help to track down when the connection is getting closed, and help you figure out why hopefully. Maybe some other app is closing the network for some reason. You can see the docs and download it here https://developer.att.com/aro